# React testing custom hook with window.url

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a custom hook that downloads a file from an url, it works fine and now I trying to test its behaviour.

```
const useFileDownload = ({ apiResponse, fileName }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  const download = async () => {
    const { data } = await apiResponse()
    const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]))

    setUrl(objectUrl)
    setName(fileName)

    ref.current?.click()
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)
  }

  return { url, ref, name, download }
}
```

I call like this on my component

```
  const { ref, url, download, name } = useFileDownload({
    apiResponse: () => axios.get(pdfUrl, { responseType: 'blob' }),
    fileName: 'my_custom.pdf'
  })
...
...
   // this stay hidden on my component
   <a href={url} download={name} ref={ref} />
```

And my test

```
describe('useFileDownload', () => {
  it('should create refs', async () => {
    window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn()
    const mockRequest = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 'url/to/pdf' })
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFileDownload({ apiResponse: mockRequest, fileName: 'sample.pdf' }))

    act(() => {
      result.current.download()
    })

    expect(result.current.name).toBe('sample.pdf')
    expect(mockRequest).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

I'm trying to mock createObjectURL, but it doesn't seem to work, and I don't know if its the right way. If the line containing window.URL fails, then the rest of the code fails on the assertion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

Option 1. **Using asynchronous version [`act()`](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md#async--await) function**

Option 2. **Using [waitForNextUpdate()](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#async-utilities), see [example](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#async)**

> Sometimes, a hook can trigger asynchronous updates that will not be immediately reflected in the `result.current` value. Luckily, `renderHook` returns some utilities that allow the test to wait for the hook to update using async/await (or just promise callbacks if you prefer). The most basic async utility is called `waitForNextUpdate`.

```
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useFileDownload } from './useFileDownload';

describe('useFileDownload', () => {
  it('should create refs', async () => {
    window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL = jest.fn();
    const mockRequest = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 'url/to/pdf' });
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useFileDownload({ apiResponse: mockRequest, fileName: 'sample.pdf' }));

    // option 1
    // await act(async () => {
    //   await result.current.download();
    // });

    // option 2
    result.current.download();
    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(result.current.name).toBe('sample.pdf');
    expect(mockRequest).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75393013/useFileDownload.test.ts (10.519 s)
  useFileDownload
    ✓ should create refs (21 ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useFileDownload.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 15                
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.205 s
```

package version:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1"
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
}
```

Comment: thanks! I tried the first option and it worked flawlessly, but for some reason option 2 didn't worked for me

Comment: @hirosk Updated jest config and package version, please confirm it